# Selenium web driver test in Edge browser throws null pointer exception

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

While running the below `Selenium Web driver` test in java for Edge browser, it throws `null pointer` exception. But the test runs successfully for the chrome browser, could someone please advise about the problem here ?

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> payment.tests.BaseTest.beforeMethod(BaseTest.java:33)     at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:135)
> at
> org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:64)
> at
> org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:364)

`testng.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" thread-count="1" parallel="tests" >
<test name="RepayCalculatorTestChrome">
<parameter name="browser" value="Chrome" />
<packages>
    <package name="payment.tests" />
</packages>
</test>
<test name="RepayCalculatorTestEdge">
<parameter name="browser" value="Edge" />
<packages>
    <package name="payment.tests"/>
</packages>
</test>
</suite>
```

`BaseTest.java`

```
public class BaseTest {

    public WebDriver driver;
    public EdgeDriver edgeDriver;

    @BeforeMethod
    @Parameters("browser")
    public void beforeMethod(String browser) {
        //Check if parameter passed from TestNG is 'Edge'
        String localDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("edge")){
            //set path to msedgedriver.exe
            System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver",localDir + "\\resources\\msedgedriver.exe");
            System.out.println("Edge Driver started...");
            edgeDriver.manage().window().maximize();
            edgeDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            edgeDriver.get("test_url_here");
        }
        //Check if parameter passed from Testng is 'chrome'
        else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){
            //set path to chromedriver.exe
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",localDir + "\\resources\\chromedriver.exe");
            System.out.println("Chrome Driver started...");
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            //options.addArguments("--headless");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("test_url_here");
        }
        
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        if (driver != null || edgeDriver !=null) {
            driver.quit();
            System.out.println("Driver get instantiated. Quitting..");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Driver is null so nothing to do");
        }
    }

}
```

`RepayCalculatorTest.java`

```
public class RepayCalculatorTest extends BaseTest {
    
    String borrowAmount = "750000";
    String interestAmount = "2";
    String loanTerm = "30";
    
    @Test(enabled = true)
    public void loanRepayCalculator() throws InterruptedException {
        RepayCalculatorPage repayCalculator = new RepayCalculatorPage(driver);
        repayCalculator.setBorrowAmount(borrowAmount);
        WebElement webElement1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Enter interest rate']"));
        webElement1.clear();
        repaymentCalculator.setInterestAmount(interestAmount);
        WebElement webElement2= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Enter loan term']"));
        webElement2.clear();
        repaymentCalculator.setLoanTerm(loanTerm);
        repaymentCalculator.getCalculateLoanPaymentBtn();
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(7, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        WebElement resultElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='calculatedresult']//div[@class='_3Kmts']//div[@class='ant-row _2kHnl']//div[contains(@class,'z-k7K ant-col-xs-24')]//p[@class='_3TRls _2fRgA']")));
        String resultText = resultElement.getText();
        System.out.println("EMI amount:"+resultText);
        Assert.assertEquals("$2,772 / month*", resultText);
    }

}
```

Comment: I have initialized `public EdgeDriver edgeDriver = null;` in BaseTest.java. But still its throwing error.

Comment: @arundeepchohan I have initialized public EdgeDriver edgeDriver = null; in BaseTest.java. But still getting the error and no difference

Comment: @arundeepchohan I have set a break point, i am getting edge browser null inside BaseTest > edge case

Comment: public static WebDriver driver; try swapping over to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues in your code.

**First:**

Here:

```java
if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("edge")){
    //set path to msedgedriver.exe
    System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver",localDir + "\\resources\\msedgedriver.exe");
    System.out.println("Edge Driver started...");
    edgeDriver.manage().window().maximize();
    edgeDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    edgeDriver.get("test_url_here");
}
```

you call `edgeDriver.manage()` however `edgeDriver` field has not been initialized.

**Second:**

Even if you fix your bug with `edgeDriver` field initialization. Your tests work with `driver` field. When you run it for chrome you initialize `driver` field so that your tests work fine.

When you run your code for Edge, your code initializes `edgeDriver` leaving your `driver` field referring to `null`. Since your tests work with `driver` field which is left referring to `null`, you get `NullPointerException`.

**This code should work better:**

```java
@BeforeMethod
@Parameters("browser")
public void beforeMethod(String browser) {
    //Check if parameter passed from TestNG is 'Edge'
    String localDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("edge")){
        //set path to msedgedriver.exe
        System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver",localDir + "\\resources\\msedgedriver.exe");
        System.out.println("Edge Driver started...");
        driver = new EdgeDriver();
    }
    //Check if parameter passed from Testng is 'chrome'
    else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){
        //set path to chromedriver.exe
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",localDir + "\\resources\\chromedriver.exe");
        System.out.println("Chrome Driver started...");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        //options.addArguments("--headless");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    }
    
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("test_url_here");

}
```

Comment: Alexey R , Thank you very much, I find out that last day and my test ran successfully. Appreciate your detailed answer. Upvoted and accepted.